# Angular Service Worker issue when opening App page in new Tab

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-service-worker

Angular 7 app with service-worker re-direct to a new tab and a new page on the same application does not work.
I have a link that I email users which once clicked, would send the user to www.mysite.com/mymessages.  After I have enabled the service worker,  the link does not work.
I have been changing the service-worker configuration, including and excluding urls but no success.

A quick test just created a new app with a PROJECT components.  Its runs on localhost:8000, built with production flags.

```
  -works

    this.router.navigate(['/projects']); 

  -open in new Tab does not work

    window.open('localhost:8000/projects', "_blank");
```

There must be something easy that I am missing, I should be able to get to a page on my app on a new TAB.

Changing the service worker configuration doesn't seem to do anything.

Service Worker configuration:

```
 "index": "/index.html",
  "version" : 1.3,
  "dataGroups": [{
    "name": "api-freshness",
    "urls": [
      "!/**/mymessages"
    ],
    "version" : 1,
    "cacheConfig": {
      "strategy": "freshness",
      "maxSize": 100,
      "maxAge": "3d",
      "timeout": "10s"
    }
  }
```

Should be able to open new page in new Tab, but just isn't working for me.

UPDATE - removing localhost:8000 from window.open will work for my test example.  But the main issue remain ... being able to go to a specific page on my site by clicking on a URL link in an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this

```
window.open('/projects', "_blank");
```

Comment: Thanks, removing the 'localhost:8000' from window.open works when I am already on my site.  But the main issue is sending a link to an email and having them be able to navigate back to a specific page on my site.  So the link would be something like www.mysite.com/pagex.  When clicking on the link, they cannot navigate to the specific page.

Comment: In case of email, u have to send entire link like www.mysite.com/pagex @GabrielO